# Pivoting on a field?

Tags: sql, db2

I use IBM DB2 SQL.

Here is my current query:

```
select 
EXSHPE as "Shape",
EXDLVY as "Delivery",

  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'Print' Then EXRLTO Else 0 End) As Retail_Print,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'Pattern' Then EXRLTO Else 0 End) as Retail_Pattern,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'Solid' Then EXRLTO Else 0 End) As Retail_Solid,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'UnknownA' Then EXRLTO Else 0 End) as Retail_UnknownA,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'UnknownB' Then EXRLTO Else 0 End) As Retail_UnknownB,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'UnknownC' Then EXRLTO Else 0 End) as Retail_UnknownC,

  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'Print' Then EXWHLO Else 0 End) As Wholesale_Print,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'Pattern' Then EXWHLO Else 0 End) as Wholesale_Pattern,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'Solid' Then EXWHLO Else 0 End) As Wholesale_Solid,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'UnknownA' Then EXWHLO Else 0 End) as Wholesale_UnknownA,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'UnknownB' Then EXWHLO Else 0 End) As Wholesale_UnknownB,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'UnknownC' Then EXWHLO Else 0 End) as Wholesale_UnknownC,

  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'Print' Then EXUNTO Else 0 End) As Units_Print,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'Pattern' Then EXUNTO Else 0 End) as Units_Pattern,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'Solid' Then EXUNTO Else 0 End) As Units_Solid,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'UnknownA' Then EXUNTO Else 0 End) as Units_UnknownA,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'UnknownB' Then EXUNTO Else 0 End) As Units_UnknownB,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'UnknownC' Then EXUNTO Else 0 End) as Units_UnknownC,

  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'Print' Then EXAURA Else 0 End) As Actual_AUR_Print,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'Pattern' Then EXAURA Else 0 End) as Actual_AUR_Pattern,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'Solid' Then EXAURA Else 0 End) As Actual_AUR_Solid,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'UnknownA' Then EXAURA Else 0 End) as Actual_AUR_UnknownA,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'UnknownB' Then EXAURA Else 0 End) As Actual_AUR_UnknownB,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'UnknownC' Then EXAURA Else 0 End) as Actual_AUR_UnknownC,

  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'Print' Then EXMERA Else 0 End) As Merch_AUR_Print,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'Pattern' Then EXMERA Else 0 End) as Merch_AUR_Pattern,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'Solid' Then EXMERA Else 0 End) As Merch_AUR_Solid,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'UnknownA' Then EXMERA Else 0 End) as Merch_AUR_UnknownA,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'UnknownB' Then EXMERA Else 0 End) As Merch_AUR_UnknownB,
  Sum(Case When EXSURF = 'UnknownC' Then EXMERA Else 0 End) as Merch_AUR_UnknownC

from EXOWMSPD
Where (EXCO || '/' || EXDIV)  = ?
Group By
  EXSHPE,
  EXDLVY
Order By
  EXSHPE DESC,
  EXDLVY DESC
```

Database looks like this:
[image]

I need to pivot of Surface, but dynamically.
The issue is, I only know the first 3 surface descriptions. But I need to be ready for up to 6.

Is there a way I could pivot this dynamically to grab the first 6 surfaces.

Example,

```
RETAIL_DOLLARS_1   10.00
RETAIL_DOLLARS_2   20.00
RETAIL_DOLLARS_3   50.00
RETAIL_DOLLARS_4   0.00
RETAIL_DOLLARS_5   0.00
RETAIL_DOLLARS_6   0.00
```

In this example, data was found for 3 surfaces, the other 3 I want filled with 0s.

I'm using this to make a report and I'll hide columns which will have SURFACE_DESCRIPTION_X equal to "".

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of DB2?  iSeries I know doesn't have a `PIVOT()`-type function - you'd have to manually pivot it.  However, your current `WHERE` clause will perform _terribly_ (because you can't use any indices on `EXCO`/`EXDIV`) - you'd be better served by splitting your host-variable in your program code, and comparing the fields separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to cube the data on the various dimensions, try the

```
 GROUP BY CUBE
```

clause